# Oracle : Create table in another schema and grant select and insert on it from the same schema

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, logic

I have two schemas.

1.Schema ***A***

2.Schema ***B***

I need to do following.

1. I want create some tables in schema ***B*** (same as some tables in ***A***)
2. Then Move data from ***A*** to ***B***.

Now I want to do ALL this from schema ***A***. I have written a package which when executed in ***A*** will create all the tables in ***B*** and then create synonyms for them in ***A***. And then will just select data from its own tables and insert into ***B's*** tables.

***VERY IMP :*** Now this entire thing has to happen in one go. Just an execution of one begin block should do the entire job.

***Problem :*** But now the synonyms would not work because Schema ***A*** does not have any privs on the tables it created in ***B*** .

so is there a way to create tables (from A to B ) with all the privs given at the creation time ?
Or can the schemas be switched in PL-SQL while execution so that privs can be granted from B to A ? (I am sure this can not be done, but nothing is impossible they say ! :O :P so asking )

Please help me guys ! All suggestions are welcome !

***The Main objective of this job is to do it in one go and from only one schema.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a procedure which will run under definer rights, instead of caller rights

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE definer_test AUTHID DEFINER IS 
BEGIN
    ...
END definer_test;
```

You would define such a procedure in schema B, which does the job and call it from schema A.

Comment: Thanks Olivier ! Seems this can do the job